# Chrome closes immediately after being opened with selenium (Python)

Tags: python, selenium, google-chrome

I've tried every solution I could find.

I'm trying to open Chrome with selenium for Imgur authentication purposes. here's the code:

```
def imgur_auth():
     imgur_id = 'NO'
     imgur_secret = 'NO'
     client = ImgurClient(imgur_id, imgur_secret)
     imgur_name = 'NO'
     imgur_password = 'NO'
     imgur_auth_url = client.get_auth_url('pin')
     driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=r'NO\Python\other\chromedriver')
     driver.get(imgur_auth_url)

imgur_auth()
```

right after Chrome opens and loads the page, it immediately closes.

help?

Comment: It's because it has nothing more to do, so the program closes itself. Try adding more commands for driver to do, then I think you'll understand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

as you called driver var inside function it terminates after the execution of function.

try removing the function and run